# ModelBuilder adds numerous file extensions to outputs as it runs?

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, modelbuilder, kml

Using ArcMap 10.3 I am trying to create a model that will take all the shapefiles in a folder and convert them to KML files. I first create an inline variable for the shapefiles in the folder, then when I convert them to feature classes in a geodatabase (because the layer to kml tool needs layer files as input), my output ends up at `%variable%.shp.shp.shp.shp...` etc. Then it fails on the next tool, which is converting those feature classes to layer files. I have attached two screenshots.

Does anyone know why I might be getting multiple `.shp` extensions when converting shapefiles to feature classes?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

When using an inline variable you dont need to type the .shp extension afterword. It will be automatically assigned.

Comment: Thanks @KGR, that makes sense, but when I remove the .shp from the input features in the picture above, I get the error 000732, Input Features: Dataset %full_perimeter% does not exist or is not supported. So I am confused on how I am supposed to use the variable %full_perimeter% that I created when I iterated the feature class it came from, further down the line in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Export your tool into a script and add these 2 lines according to your files, wherever you are giving names.
[image: An example of code to split your name]

Answer (score -1):

Split the name of the file using a dot (.), use the first part for name and add extension using a + sign.

Comment: Split how, can you edit your question and add more details?